# Creating a Sudoku in Java

Tags: java, creation, sudoku

I'm creating a program that invents a new Sudoku puzzle. The way I initially planned on doing this is by inventing a new puzzle and then removing random numbers. However, the algorithm I use (seen below) to create a new puzzle can take up to 5 minutes to make one. Does anyone have any faster solutions?

### Creation Algorithm

---

```
    for (int x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++) //boardWidth is the number of fillable squares wide and high the board is. (9 for a standard Sudoku board)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < boardWidth; y++)
      {
        int errorCount = 0;
        do
        {
          boardVals[y][x] = (byte)(rand.nextInt(boardWidth) + 1);
          errorCount++;
          if (errorCount > Math.pow(boardWidth, 4)) //If the square has been tried to be filled up to boardWidth^4 times (6,561 for a standard Sudoku board), it clears the board and starts again.
          {
            resetBoard();
            x = 0; y = 0; break;
          }
        }while (!boardIsOK()); //boardIsOK() is a method that checks to see if the board is solvable, ignoring unfilled squares.
      }
    }
```

### Methods:

---

```
  private boolean boardIsOK()
  {
    for (int i=0; i < boardWidth; i++)
    {
      if (!setIsOK(getRow(i)))
      {
        return false;
      }
      if (!setIsOK(getCol(i)))
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (int x=0; x < boardSegs; x++)
    {
      for (int y=0; y < boardSegs; y++)
      {
        if (!areaIsOK(getSquare(x,y)))
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }



  private byte[] getRow(int index)
  {
    return boardVals[index];
  }

  private byte[] getCol(int index)
  {
    byte[] b = new byte[boardWidth];
    for (int i=0; i < boardWidth; i++)
      b[i] = boardVals[i][index];
    return b;
  }

  private byte[][] getSquare(int xIndex, int yIndex)
  {
    byte w = (byte)(boardWidth / boardSegs), b[][] = new byte[w][w];
    for (int x=0; x < b.length; x++)
    {
      for (int y=0; y < b[x].length; y++)
      {
        b[y][x] = boardVals[y + (yIndex * w)][x + (xIndex * w)];
      }
    }
    return b;
  }

  private boolean setIsOK(byte[] set)
  {
    for (int i=0; i < set.length - 1; i++)
    {
      for (int j=i + 1; j < set.length; j++)
      {
        if (set[i] == set[j] && set[i] != NULL_VAL && set[j] != NULL_VAL)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private boolean areaIsOK(byte[][] area)
  {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < area.length; i++)
    {
      size += area[i].length;
    }
    byte[] b = new byte[size];
    for (int x=0, i=0; x < area.length; x++)
    {
      for (int y=0; y < area[x].length; y++, i++)
      {
        b[i] = area[x][y];
      }
    }
    return setIsOK(b);
  }
```

resetBoard() simply fills the board with NULL_VAL.

Comment: Describe the constraints to the problem in Prolog and run that program using [TuProlog](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/), a library for embedding Prolog in Java environments.

Comment: dunno what that is or how it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several optimization approaches possible here. First, you should add some bookkeeping to each cell, having a set of the "still possible numbers" for each of the 81 cells. Instead of taking an arbitrary random number, take a random number from this set when you fill the next cell.

And don't stop when you had 6,561 unsuccessful tries. Stop when one of the 81 sets goes empty. When this is the case, you should not throw the board away and start over again, but go one step backwards and try another value for the previous cell. Try to make a complete [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algo from that.

Comment: Sounds good... Can you come up with any code to help me out? I'm not sure I fully understand you; I can speak English, but I'm fluent in Java. ;3

Comment: @Supuhstar: why don't you give it a try by yourself and when you accomplish any difficulties, come back and ask again?

Comment: alright, I'll do that tomorrow; This is enough for a day's work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at D. Knuth's [Dancing Links](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz) (gzipped postscript) paper. With his method, you can have a really fast sudoku solver and then you can solve your board to check if it's OK.

As an idea, for [Project Euler problem 96](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=96), my Java implementation gives the solution (i.e. solve the 50 sudokus) in:

```
real   0m0.357s
user   0m0.350s
sys    0m0.010s
```

(Ubuntu Linux 2.6.32-26-server x86_64 GNU/Linux, running on an "Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  330   @ 1.60GHz")

Comment: That's a pretty advanced technique for making a really fast SuDoKu solver. I would suggest the OP to get some experience with some  simpler backtracking techniques before he is going to crack that nut.

Comment: @Doc Brown, I think it was worth mentioning it and I agree with your point

Comment: as a note, I'm not looking to solve it. I am looking to create it.

Comment: @Supuhstar: the second part of your algo should not just remove some random numbers. If you want "good" SuDoKus, it should make sure your board is still solvable in a *unique* way. Therefore you will need a solver which does not only solve a board, but tries to find every possible solution (it can stop when the 2nd solution was found, but the needed backtracking algo is almost the same).

Comment: Dancing Links is the stuff.  I tried to roll my own Sudoku generator and realized it was just dumb.  DLX is fast, and is pretty simple.  i can generate a puzzle in javascript in a few thousandths of a second with it.  If you want to see it, its a free app in the chrome store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ifaabgmcffhggbfgjknkgenljelbocin

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that removing random numbers is a good idea.

Post here the other methods: `boadIsOK()` and `resetBoard()` and read some articles how to create the puzzle ([1](http://www.sudokuonline.us/make_your_own_sudoku_puzzle2.php)).

Comment: the question was about the first part of the algo, the creation, not the removing. And removing numbers from a complete board is a standard Sudoku creation algo.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I know, but removing them randomly can result in unsolvable puzzle.

Comment: to be more precise, it can result in a puzzle which has more than one valid solution. That is typically something one should avoid when creating "interesting" SuDoKus.